# netbeans cakephp unittest PHP Fatal error: Class 'App' not found in {filename} line 3

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, netbeans-7

I am trying to run unit test from netbeans but it fails with this error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App' not found in /home/user/cakephp/app/Test/Case/Model/AceScoreTest.php on line 3
Stack trace:
1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:46
3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:150
5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:124
6. NetBeansSuite::suite() /usr/local/netbeans-7.2.1/php/phpunit/NetBeansSuite.php:0
```

Unit test works fine when run from the command line as
`./cake test app Model/AceScore`

What do I need to do to get cakephp unit test to work in Netbeans?
There must be some way to tell phpunit to look for App.php in `lib/Cake/Core/App.php`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you have to create a bootstrap file for PHPUnit and set it to NetBeans.

I have added new Action (PHPUnit Test Init Action[1]) to CakePHP pluign for NetBeans[2].
If you are using this plugin, please try it ;) Please see [1] about bootstrap file.

[1] https://github.com/junichi11/cakephp-netbeans#phpunit-test-settings-phpunit-test-init-action
[2] http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44579/php-cakephp-framework